# Creating an IntegerField in Django with an upper bound

Tags: django, django-models

In Django, is there a way to create an `IntegerField` in my model where I enforce an upper bound (e.g. an integer field where the value can't go higher than 10)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#using-validators), specifically the [`MaxValueValidator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/validators/#maxvaluevalidator)

> Raises a ValidationError with a code of 'max_value' if value is greater than max_value.

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator
my_field = IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(10)])
```

Comment: Oh I see. Missed that one. Thanks!

Comment: @HassanBaig - No worries, enjoy!